# Examples of ě₁ palatalization

Tags: historical-linguistics, slavic-languages, palatalization

"The distinction between *ě₁ and *ě₂ is based on etymology and have different effects on a preceding consonant: *ě₁ triggers the first palatalization and then becomes *a, while *ě₂ triggers the second palatalization and does not change."
from [Proto-Slavic_language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proto-Slavic_language#Alternations)
I didn't find any example of ě₁ palatalization.
google gives only 50 not unique results [at all](https://www.google.com/search?q=%C4%9B%E2%82%81) 
I need help.

Comment: Unfortunately, the Wikipedia article you linked does not have many footnotes giving the source of particular claims. I have [asked](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_talk:Rua#Question_about_palatalization_in_Slavonic) the Wikipedia editor who actually inserted that text in 2013 if they can elucidate.

Comment: @AlexB. Unfortunately you are wrong. *ě₁ and *ě₂ is a convenient way to distinguish between Proto-Slavic **ě**  (PIE *ē) and Proto-Slavic **ě** (PIE *ai, *oi)

Answer (score 3):

What is often marked ě in Slavic studies was probably actually a long e (*ē, with some unspecified degree of openness). I am not sure there is any widely accepted intermediate *ě₁ that would be clearly distinct from the original *ē. One could simply consider *C₁ē > *C₂a.

The examples that changed to an "a" could be:

mozg‑ē‑nos > mozd’žanъ > moždanъ > možd’žanъ > možd’anъ > (OCS можданъ - marrow)

(compare with mozg, мозг - brain)

or

pisk‑ē‑la (or [piskělь](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Reconstruction:Proto-Slavic/pi%C5%A1%C4%8Dal%D1%8C)) > pištalь (OCS пищаль - flute)

(compare with pískati, пискати - sqeak)

(from https://www.czechency.org/slovnik/PALATALIZACE - in Czech)

Comment: What is often marked ě in Slavic studies was  actually a long e PIE *ē, PS ě₁ (с**ѣ**ꙗти, в**ѣ**ꙗти compare s**o**w but s**ee**d) and actually a PIE ai/oi ě₂ (хл**ѣ**бъ, д**ѣ**лити compare l**oa**f, d**ea**l (+ i mutation)) Thanks for the examples

Comment: @fedor Please understand that what you mark ѣ  was no modern Russian е sound. The reconstruction of Proto-Slavic ě/ѣ is much more problematic. And do not argue with modern English, for god's sake, that went hrough way too many sound changes.

Comment: @fedor Please read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yat for introduction, but it does not contain everything. But it is quite clear that yat was some kind of long e.

Comment: Vladimir извини, с реконструкцией ятя всё ясно и у меня сейчас вопрос закрыт, я привёл тебе пример с sow ибо англ. o sow ~ др.англ. a sa(w)an ~ готское ai saian (которое также как и в славянском ять имеет две природы ē и ai) "Similarly, verb stems ending in -ái-, -áu-, **-ē-**, -iu-, and -ō- become -aj-, -aw, **-ai-**, -iw, and -au- respectively;" поэтому sow но seed, извини пока больше отвечать не буду, пока по-английски сформулирую день пройдёт времени нету, можем списаться где-нибудь, если хочешь